# Looking for smart way to redesign this and/or statement

Tags: javascript

I need to rewrite the last part of the condition. I need both and/or together.

```
if ((params.path === 'ABC' || params.path === 'EFG') && 
(params.noPath && params.fClick))
```

Like params.noPath &&|| params.click====> over here I need only one or both conditions to be true. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you already have?

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it?

Comment: One or both == `params.noPath || params.click` O.o

Comment: I don't know if the logic is correct in the case of - is this situation *valid*. However, I can read and understand the logic right now. So I'm not sure why if a re-write is warranted.

Comment: `true || true` is `true`, it is not exclusive.

Comment: For the last part I have two scenarios. In one scenario I need both params and other scenario I need only one params.

Comment: Reminds me a friend who were learning programming. He asked me how to write a *"and or" I asked him what this is supposed to be, he told me *"one or the other or one and the other"*.

Comment: do you have some values for the given condition and the wanted result?

Comment: @Adnan in which cases you need both and in whiches you need **only 1** of them ?

Comment: @Cid very good question. The explanation isn't very clear - we probably need the truth table for this and work backwards. Although at that point OP might as well use an online tool that turns a truth table into a boolean logic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate an XOR (XOR is the combinai) with javascript like this :

```
(params.noPath && !params.fClick) || ( !params.noPath && params.fClick)
```

[Reference](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html)

More smaller way with ternary :

```
if ( params.noPath ? !params.fClick : params.fClick )
```

---

> The XOR operation can be described as "return true if the two boolean operands do not have the same value"

So the simplest, cleanest version of the XOR operator, that works with any data types, including expressions is :

```
if ( !params.noPath != !params.fClick )
```

Comment: um. why not just `params.noPath !== params.fClick` ?!

Comment: `false !== undefined` <-- true

Comment: @Cid With "!" that works with any data types, including expressions

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It is something I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to re-phrase the boolean logic to represent XOR. Just use `^` and, if needed, parse the left and right hand sides as booleans. The result would be `0` or `1` which parsed into a boolean would be `false` or `true` respectively. So you can do `Boolean(a ^ b)` for any boolean values of `a` and `b` or do the implicit cast via `!!(a ^ b)`

Comment: @VLAZ `^` is a **bitwise** `XOR`, not the boolean operator

Comment: @Cid again, if `a` and `b` are booleans you would get the same as the boolean truth table for XOR `true ^ true` -> `0`, `true ^ false` -> `1`, `false ^ true` -> `1`, `false ^ false` -> `0`. You do get `0` and `1` yes, but *again* convert that into boolean via `Boolean` as a function or an implicit cast with `!!` and you're done `0` -> `false` and `1` -> `true`. Inside an `if` statement you don't even need the conversion. There is no need to re-jig the boolean logic to reinvent XOR.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just need to swap the && for ||

```
if ((params.path === 'ABC' || params.path === 'EFG') && (params.noPath || params.fClick))
```

Because "one or both" logically is the same as at least one of them being true.

The above will return true if path is ABC or EFG and noPath is true.

The above will return true if path is ABC or EFG and fClick is true.

The above will return true if path is ABC or EFG and noPath and fClick are true.

Else it will return false